# Equivalent one liner in tcl for an if statement and puts

Tags: perl, unix, tcl

I have code in tcl for which i want to print only if a variable is enabled. I want to do this in one line if possible.

```
#in perl 
print "Device name $dev" if(-e $debug);
#in tcl
if {[tvf::svrf debug ]}{
    puts "Device name is $dev"
}
```

Comment: The tcl equivalent to perl's `-e $filename` is [`file exists $filename`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/file.htm#M15).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd split that over multiple lines *unless* there's going to be many places where you take that decision. If you're doing it in many places, it's better to set up a procedure:

```
# A single-line way to write this
proc writeDebugMessage args [lindex {{} {puts [lindex $args 0]}} [tvf::svrf debug]]

# At the places where you want to print a message in some cases
writeDebugMessage "Device name is $dev"
```

That procedure definition is a one-liner way to write this longer version:

```
if {[tvf::svrf debug]} {
    proc writeDebugMessage args {puts [lindex $args 0]}
} else {
    # This exact form of procedure gets bytecode compiled into nothingness; max efficiency!
    proc writeDebugMessage args {}
}
```

If this was my real code, I'd use the longer version or even more verbosity!

---

A true one-liner version is possible, and this is about as short as it gets:

```
[lindex {list puts} [tvf::svrf debug]] "Device name is $dev"
```

*Not recommended!* Defining a helper procedure produces a lot more readable code!

Comment: I really hope there's not now code floating around OP's work that uses that last one.

Answer (score 1):

```
if {[tvf::svrf debug ]} { puts "Device name is $dev" }
```

Comment: is there anything better than this?

Comment: “Better” is very much a matter of perspective. There isn't a world shortage of newlines.

Answer (score 0):

Tcl does not accomodate Perl's statement modifiers. This is entirely due to Tcl's `command arg arg ...` syntax.

If you like that style, you can create a helper proc:

```
proc do {script if condition} {
    if {$if ne "if"} {
        error "some usage message"
    }
    if {[uplevel [list expr $condition]]} {
        uplevel $script
    }
}
```

Then:

```
% set debug true
true
% do {puts "I'm debugging"} if {$debug}
I'm debugging
% set debug false
false
% do {puts "I'm debugging"} if {$debug}
%
```

That `do` proc can be extended with  `do ... while ...`  etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
set dev debug_device
interp alias {} print {} apply {{args {dbg 0}} {expr {$dbg?$args:{}}}}

set debug true
print "Device name is $dev" $debug
```

A quick one-liner alias with apply as the anonymous function.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing can rightly prevent you from defining this simple Perl command in Tcl:

```
proc print {msg args} {
  # never mind, this is for fun only
  if {[string match "if(-e *)" $args]} {
    if {[string range $args 6 end-1]} {puts $msg}
  } else {
    # other Perl stuff whatever it was
  }
}
```

... and use this Perlish **print** in Tcl:

```
set dev "'Perl device'"
# ------------
set debug true
print "Device name $dev" if(-e $debug)
print "Is it true?" if(-e true)
print "Is it false?" if(-e false)
# ------------
set debug false
print "2. Device name $dev" if(-e $debug)
print "2. Is it true?" if(-e true)
print "2. Is it false?" if(-e false)
```

This way you might redefine all of Perl in Tcl ;-)